# Не отображается ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день, у меня почему-то в приложении не отображается ListView. При нажатии на кнопку информация не появляется на экране.

Ошибка:

10-06 06:52:53.202 15580-15580/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10061: Read-only file system

Код:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private View parentView;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
    private ContactAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.string_click_to_load, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull final View view) {
                if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    final ProgressDialog dialog;

                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_title));
                    dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_message));
                    dialog.show();

                    ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();

                    Call<ContactList> call = api.getMyJSON();

                    call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactList>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call, Response<ContactList> response) {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                contactList = response.body().getContacts();

                                adapter = new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ContactList> call, Throwable t) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Пройдите дебагером или расставьте логи, чтобы понять, на каком шаге что-то пошло не так. Может проверка интернета не проходит, может запрос попадает в `onFailure` (добавьте туда `t.printStackTrace()`), а может и просто возвращается пустой лист.

Comment: eugeneek, действительно сначала срабатывает checkConnection,  а потом onFailure. Что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стектрейс ошибки, полученный с помощью `t.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
                                             
                                             [ 10-06 07:53:50.438   570:  585 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf6a13050, tid 585

Comment: @Anna13 проверьте в манифесте наличие `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`